# enter webpage authentication with webclient that's not overloaded in "System.Net.NetworkCredential" in c#

Tags: c#, authentication, web-scraping, webclient

I'm trying to connect and download website content that requires an authentication that is not "overloaded".

The options are:

- user
- user+password,
- user+password+domain

I need user+subscriber+password. How can i pass this credentials?

code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();  
public void search()  
{  
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, subscriber, password); //not really exist  
        Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData("https://example.com/");
...  
}
```

Comment: Telling us what `https://thewebsite.i.need/` is will go a long way to someone being able to help you.

Comment: sorry, it's work-related internal website. you wont have access to it

Comment: @ModusRoeiPonens Please add answer to this question below and accept it when you are able in a couple of days so that we can all benefit.

Comment: If you want to answer you own question, do so in an answer. Don't edit the title add add SOLVED to it. If you do want to write an answer, then make sure it is comprehensive. If you can't be bothered to do that, delete the question.

Comment: didn't know, answer added.

Answer (score 1):

How i solved the problem:
used a POST method with improvedWebClient class, that is like webclient but one that saves cookies. you can find it [here](http://www.codingvision.net/tips-and-tricks/c-webclient-with-cookies/).
code:

```
ImprovedWebClient wc = new ImprovedWebClient();
wc.DownloadData("https://theWebSite.com"); //to enter home page and get cookie
string URI = "https://theWebSite.com/authenticate"; //the login page
string myParameters = "user=theUserName&subscriber_number=1234-5678&password=myPassword&commit=LogIn"; //the parameters for the website
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
```

thanks for the help guys.